# Bootstrap 3 carousel img/indicator not showing properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm still very new to bootstrap/programming html in general as this is a new hobby. I have difficulty using the carousel properly and the next questions should take seconds to anybody I guess but I've been messing with codes for an hour and I can't still find why...

I copy/pasted the given code on bootstrap's site and filled the fields with proper items (used .svg for bg img, named the id differently but changed all the other ids too.). Maybe someone could tell me why the indicators/img are not fitted properly. i.e.: indicators are at the top left corner just like any other ordered list bullets and img show underneath them.

```
in head there is
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


---    


<div class="container">                 
                                                    <!--    CAROUSEL -->
<div id="mon-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width: 450; height: 250; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;>
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#mon-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#mon-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#mon-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides  -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img/solid-black.svg" alt="fond-gris" style="width: 450; height: 250;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>TEST CAPTION 1</h3>
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="img/solid-black.svg" alt="fond-gris" style="width: 450; height: 250;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>TEST CAPTION 2</h3>
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="img/solid-black.svg" alt="fond-gris" style="width: 450; height: 250;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>TEST CAPTION 2</h3>
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mon-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mon-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
                                                    <!-- CAROUSEL   -->
</div>
```

Comment: We need code in order to debug please

Answer (score 0):

Your webpage is most probably missing the required bootstrap files.

Add this line to your `<head>....</head>` section:

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And this line below your jQuery script line:

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that when I used style in the carousel's div it was the source of the problem... I guess I'll have to find an other way around to size the carousel.